i got an error when i tried to upload the post in WordPress
This was first answer :
The webpage at https://**********/wp-admin/post.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
the second one :
This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at https://*********/wp-admin/post.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
we used Let's encrypt SSL
recently checked the htaccess and i just found WP Rocket and Wordfence and WP  default settings.
we actived all log and got gravity forms problem. also checked the error files and debug.log. everything was clear.

You cannot upload posts to wordpress. Did you mean update?

What kind of gravity form problems? Are they still there? Do you think it has something to do with the problem? Did you deactivate the plugin in order to check that the problem is gone?
